# What packages do I need to install in order to bulld postgres from source?

Tags: compiling, make, postgresql

I need to be able to build postgres-8.4.2 from source. What dependencies should I install?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're interested in `sudo apt-get build-dep postgresql-8.4`.